# How correct open connections to database in Python/Django

Tags: mysql, django, design-patterns

I want know how open correctly new connection to database. A problem rise when i want create single QUERY to database, from many places in my code. For example, one request is sent to database from login.html , second from register page, third to gallery in index.html . I guess , should i use some project patterns? Do you have some suggestion ?

I have written this class which are responsible for connection to mysql database. I suppose that it is very wrong (i don't focus yet on validation - but i know about that):

```py
import mysql.connector
import configparser


class DataBaseConnectionHandler(object):
    __DATABASE = ""
    user = ""
    passwd = ""
    host = ""
    fileName = ""
    dataBaseConnection = ""

    def __init__(self, fileName=None, host='localhost'):

        if fileName is not None:
            config_file = configparser.ConfigParser()
            config_file.read('shop/config/dbConfig.ini')

            database: str = config_file.get('DEFAULT', 'database')
            user: str = config_file.get('DEFAULT', 'user')
            password: str = config_file.get('DEFAULT', 'password')
            self.__DATABASE = database
            self.user = user
            self.passwd = password
            self.host = host

    def connectToDatabase(self):

        """ EXECUTE CONNECTION AND RETURN AN HOOK TO DATABASE"""

        dataBaseConnector = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=self.host,
            user=self.user,
            passwd=self.passwd,
            database=self.__DATABASE
        )

        if dataBaseConnector != "":
            self.dataBaseConnection = dataBaseConnector
            return self.dataBaseConnection
        else:
            self.dataBaseConnection = None
            return self.dataBaseConnection
```

class RegisterUser

```py
from .databses import DataBaseConnection


class RegisterUser(object):
    __formName = ""
    __formLogin = ""
    __formSurrname = ""
    __formPasswd = ""
    __fromEmail = ""

    def __init__(self, userName, userSurrname, userLogin, userPassword, userEmail):

        self.__formName         = userName
        self.__formSurrname     = userSurrname
        self.__formLogin        = userLogin
        self.__formPasswd       = userPassword
        self.__fromEmail        = userEmail

    def createUser(self):

        print("[!] Create user")
        # ------------- CONNECTION TO DATABASE ----------------
        hook = DataBaseConnection.DataBaseConnectionHandler('shop/config/dbConfig.ini').connectToDatabase()
        myCursor = hook.cursor()

        # ------------- EXECUTING MYSQL QUERY ----------------

        # [!] nie szyfruje hasła
        sqlStatment = "INSERT INTO user(Login, Password, Email, Name, Surname) " \
                      "VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}');".format(self.__formLogin,
                                                                      self.__formPasswd,
                                                                      self.__fromEmail,
                                                                      self.__formName,
                                                                      self.__formSurrname)
        myCursor.execute(sqlStatment)
        hook.commit()

        print(myCursor.rowcount, "Record inserted")
        print("[*] Executing an query")


        # ------------- CLOSE CONNECTION ----------------

        hook.close()
```

I know that Django has own way to connect to database, but it is wired for me. i had some wired error, that why i decide use PyMysql. In near time I'll change that, but it's good moment to learn how to write code correctly .

edit:

```
PycharmProjects/lovLevelMusic/lovLevelMusic/settings.py changed, reloading.
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 22, in <module>
    from MySQLdb.constants import CLIENT, FIELD_TYPE                # isort:skip
ImportError: cannot import name 'CLIENT' from 'MySQLdb.constants' (unknown location)
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'dbDjango',
       'USER': 'root',
       'PASSWORD': 'password',
       'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
       'PORT': '3306',
   }
}
```

Comment: What error you got when connecting with Django ORM ?

Comment: i updated post :)

Comment: I solved it. The solution is on this page: https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/. I had to install dependency default-libmysqlclient-dev using: sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev and after that error disappear .

Comment: WARNING: The way you're using SQL here is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. If you do have to use MySQL directly, at least use parametrized queries.

Comment: Also, it seems you're duplicating Django's views and forms functionality -- if you don't want to learn or use them, use a more bare-bones framework such as Flask.

Comment: What do you mean "duplicating Django Views" ?? I have using Django to connect with database :)